# Match LLM output to fixed ontology

Tags: llm

We have a certain fixed vocabulary or ontology and would like to match the output of a LLM to this vocabulary.

The LLM output could be either a single term, a list of terms, or free form text. For example, the vocabulary is a list of occupations, and we would like to ask "provide a list of occupations for which this skill is useful".

The solution could either be a post-processing step (which would make it useful for non-LLM-texts, too), or somehow integrated in the generation.

- For a small vocabulary, I could include it in the prompt. However the vocabulary is likely very large. Going by the identifiers alone it could also be ambiguous, like "Doctor" (of medicine or of physics).
- One thing I tried was to calculate the embedding of each term in the ontology, then the embedding of the term I would like to match, and then pick the term that is closest to that. This works for simple words or lists, but it doesn't work very well in free-form texts. I did manage to work around it, by asking the LLM to mark occupation terms with "[]". It also doesn't work well when the word alone doesn't completely define the term.

Is there any standard way to restrict or match the output of an LLM to a fixed vocabulary?

Comment: I don't know of a standard way, but there is an additional way you didn't mention. You could custom train your model on the ontology and give it prompts that heavily reward it for picking from that list. You could also add a bunch of those free form text responses that are supposed to map to particular items in your ontology. It will never be perfect, but you could also combine that with a post-processing step.

Comment: That's a good addition! As a first step we only considered techniques which dont require retraining, but I'll check that out, too.

Answer (score 1):

## Use an LLM Completion Generation Framework

Take a look at Completion Generation Frameworks such as [Guidance](https://github.com/guidance-ai/guidance) (created by Microsoft).

Here's how you would force the LLM to choose one of the selected options. The framework guarantees you get your desired output 100% of the time.

```
from guidance import user, assistant

# load a chat model
chat_lm = models.LlamaCppChat(path)

# wrap with chat block contexts
with user():
    lm = chat_lm + 'Do you want a joke or a poem?'

with assistant():
    lm += f"A {select(['joke', 'poem'])}."`
```

A side bonus is that the framework will generate the least amount of tokens needed to select an option out of the available options, this saves both generation time and compute cost. Generated tokens are marked in green.

[image]

## Frameworks available

I'll give a list of what I consider to be the top three LLM Completion Generation Frameworks as of today. Note that they have different strengths and tradeoffs.

- [Guidance](https://github.com/guidance-ai/guidance)
- [LMQL](https://github.com/eth-sri/lmql)
- [Marvin](https://github.com/PrefectHQ/marvin)

All of these should support both fixed and open-ended ontologies.

There are some frameworks as well, but they may or may not be suited to this use case and have variable levels of community support:

- https://github.com/guardrails-ai/guardrails
- https://github.com/outlines-dev/outlines
- https://github.com/1rgs/jsonformer
- https://github.com/newhouseb/clownfish
- https://github.com/jxnl/instructor
- https://github.com/knowsuchagency/struct-gpt